# Regarding Image upload and get file information models in .NET core API and Angualar

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

in one of my functionality I need to add images along with other form data so I am using form data to send the files. In the get request, I just need to show the images so I am getting the image information like path stored, name to display the images. I have created 3 separate models i.e BaseModel, GetModel, and PostModel for the same with only 1 parameter difference in getting and post. Here are my models.

```
 public class PatientInformationBaseViewModel
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public GenderViewModel gender { get; set; }
        public string history { get; set; }
        public string caseNo { get; set; }
    }

public class GetPatientInfomationViewModel: PatientInformationBaseViewModel
    {
        public FileInformationViewModel patientPhotoInformation { get; set; }
    }

 public class PostPatientInformationViewModel : PatientInformationBaseViewModel
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public IFormFile patientPhoto { get; set; }
    }
```

I have created a model to accept the formdata in the controller as

```
public class PatientInformationFormDataViewModel
    {
        public string patientInformation { get; set; }
        public IFormFile patientPhoto { get; set; }
    }
```

In the controller, I am deserializing into the post model and then sending it to my service layer. In my service layer, I am adding patient information to the database and returning the GUID which is my primary key of the table. Using the Id field I am uploading the image i.e saving files to the file system and returning the details and then calling a query to save file information in the table.

While getting the data to be displayed in the Angular table I am using GetModel as I do not need the actual file. If I combine all the models one of the parameters will be useless and remain null so I chose this approch.

Is this the correct approach or is there any better way in terms of conventions. Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot render a `FormFile` under the Image tag. You can return a string type path or url.

Comment: Didnt get your point. I am sending formdata and binding it to IFormFile in .net core API controller